# How to not show tags if the post doesn't have any?

Tags: tags

I currently have the following trying to avoid showing tags (the icon in this case) when there aren't any, but the icon continues to show up. Any thoughts?

```
<?php if ( is_singular() && function_exists('the_tags') ) : ?> 
    <p><i class="icon-tags"></i><?php the_tags('', ', ', ' '); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get a **string** value for the tags and print it only if there *are* tags:

```
$tags = get_the_tag_list('', ', ', ' ');

if ( "" !== trim( $tags ) )
{
    echo "<p><i class='icon-tags'></i>$tags</p>";
}
```

Comment: Your icon is defined in your css for the `icon-tags` class. So your code still displayed the HTML. @toscho code doesn't echo the HTML unless you have tags.

Comment: @Stephen I made an edit, the HTML should be printed now only if there are tags.

Comment: Actually I didn't catch the error. Was referring to the OP; but yes your edit is correct of course.

Comment: You could also use the OP's `the_tags('', ', ', ' ');` inside the conditional (although it would be redundant).

Answer (score 1):

you could also add the html into the 'before' parameter of [`the_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags)

for example reducing your whole code to one line:

```
<?php if ( is_singular() ) the_tags('<p><i class="icon-tags"></i>', ', ', '</p>'); ?>`
```

Comment: +1 For very short strings this is indeed the most pragmatic approach. :)